# adding stuff to an array using jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, hyperlink, concatenation

i need to know if this is possible and how....

I have a series of linkk

< a href="#" id="hello" > HELLO  < /a >

< a href="#" id="welcome" > welcome  < /a >

< a href="#" id="start" > start  < /a >

< a href="#" id="finish" > finish < /a >

what i want to do is as i click on the link I wish to add the id value to an array(words). so if i click all the 4 links my array should have hello, welcome,start,finish. Consequently if that is not possible can you concatenate them to a single variable on each click without destroying the previous data in the variable..words=(hello|welcome|start|finish).

any help is appreciated.

thanks
andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so if your js file looks like this (and jquery has been included on the page)

```
var ClickedLinks = [];
$(function () {
    $('a').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        if ($.inArray(id, ClickedLinks) == -1) {
            ClickedLinks.push(id);
        }
    });
});
```

This will check the array and NOT add it again.

EDIT: Fixed $.inArray returning a position, rather than a boolean (as I incorrectly assumed)

Comment: @alastair new thing learnt from your code , inArrya , i wrote my function uncessaryly , thanks + 1 for you

Comment: @gov: it's a really convenient little function :)

Comment: var ClickedLinks = [];
$(function () {
    $('a').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        if (!$.inArray(id, ClickedLinks)) {
            ClickedLinks.push(id);
        }
    });
    $.each(ClickedLinks, function(key, value) {
      alert(key)
});

});

 < a href="#" id="hello" class="examle"> HELLO < /a >

Comment: var ClickedLinks = [];
$(function () {
    $('a').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        if (!$.inArray(id, ClickedLinks)) {
            ClickedLinks.push(id);
        }
    });
    $.each(ClickedLinks, function(key, value) {
      alert(key)
});

});


< a href="#" id="hello" class="examle"> HELLO < /a >

it didnt work...as in no error but no output either

Comment: I made a couple of mistakes, as well as where you placed you checking code: see http://jsfiddle.net/cPUKr/3/

Comment: @andy, you also forgot to change, in jsFiddle, to use the jQuery library.

Comment: andy there is some problem with that check for array , try this link

Comment: @andy , put the foreach loop inside click if you put outside click who will trigger that to print values , one more thing is there is some problem with that check and its not adding values , try my link it sworking

Comment: @andy whenever you use jsfiddle on the left hande side select the jquery version and jquery as your javsacript///

Comment: @andy just curiosity , why do you want store all ids in a array ??

Answer (score 0):

@andy first give a class to all hrefs//

```
  < a href="#" id="hello" class="examle"> HELLO < /a >

    var arrayResults=new Array();

    $('.examle').click(function() {
        var textval= $(this).attr('id');;// do a check if it already exists
       if(!exitsts){ //write a function to check if already exists..
       arrayResults.push(textval);
       }
    });
```

finally arrayResults will have all the values

Answer (score 0):

```
var myVar = Array()

$('a').click(function(){
    myVar[] = $(this).attr('id');
})
```

Comment: you have add a check condition if it already exists//// alastair code takes care of it.